# Is there a way to get the first active bit through SQL (MySQL)?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column named `a`, and a column named `b`.

I want to fill with an `UPDATE ... SET b = ...` query the b column, so that it contains the first bit that `a` has set to 1. Okay, you probably didn't understand, it's much easier to understand with an example:

```
a = 2508 = 0x9CC = 0100111001100  
b = 4    = 0x4   = 0000000000100

a = 2080 = 0x820 = 0100000100000  
b = 32   = 0x20  = 0000000100000
```

---

Is there a way to do this in pure SQL?

Comment: In SQL server, you could write a UDF (function) to convert the value to a string (e.g. "100111001100") then use the CHARINDEX function to determine the index, then shift a "1" to the left by the appropriate amount; sorry I'm not familar enough with MySQL to say whether there is the equivalent solution.

Comment: @Kieren: I was thinking of doing it with some magic mathematical formula that probably exists but I don't know of

Comment: I'm unclear on how the value in column a is stored, and what you want column b stored as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update your_table
set b = if(a > 0,pow(2,instr(reverse(bin(a)),'1')-1),0);
```

Comment: And what if the most-significant bit is set?  I assume we can have negatives, too.

Comment: @Justin: The most significant bit is treated like all other bits. If `a` is less than or equal to 0, then I set `b` to 0.

Comment: Yeah, but if a is negative, the first bit must be set, so b will not be 0.  It would instead be INT_MIN, right?  Unless I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: @Justin: I'll leave it to the OP to decide how to handle negative values of `a` (and 0). That wasn't covered by the original examples. My code will work for those examples. For all I know the data type of `a` is unsigned, in which case this discussion is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think it is unsigned, but regardless it's a bitmask in which only 6 bits are currently used and it won't ever reach 32, so this answer worked great. Thanks!